# Knockout.js demo 'Twitter client' does not work

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

I'm studying Knockout.js and tried to make [its tutorial demo **'Twitter Client'** (This is link to the code)](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/twitter.html), but it does not work at all!

my code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/weed_7777/ZZJbv/

my CoffeeScript code is as below:

```
root = exports ? this
class root.Twitter
  constructor: ->
    @tweets = []
    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=100&q=%40weed_7777')
    .done((data) =>
      $.each data.results, (i, item) =>
        @tweets.push item
    )

root = exports ? this
class root.TweetListView
  constructor: ->
    twitter = new Twitter
    @currentTweets = ko.computed =>
      twitter.tweets

ko.applyBindings new TweetListView

$(".loadingIndicator").ajaxStart ->
    $(@).fadeIn()
.ajaxComplete ->
    $(@).fadeOut()
```

Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tweets need to be an observableArray:

```
class root.Twitter
  constructor: ->
    @tweets = ko.observableArray([])
    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=100&q=%40weed_7777')
     .done((data) =>
      $.each data.results, (i, item) =>
        @tweets.push item
     )
```

Updated fiddle works:

http://jsfiddle.net/hwRBN/